# ASP classic illogical behavior: request variables are empty if include doesn't flush

Tags: asp-classic

i have 2 files:  a.asp, inc.asp

a.asp includes inc.asp in somewhere in the beginning.
inc.asp retrieves variables from the request  e.g. z = request("z").
after that, i must write somewhere "response.flush".
if the response.flush command doesn't comes AFTER that code somewhere, then the variables (e.g. z), are empty!.

this is totally weird. why there must be a flush?

why the code *before* the flush changes its behavior ??? how does it "know" there's going to be a flush?!!?

- i couldn't reproduce it with a code sample, i'll try to put here the code itself, but it's quite big.
- IIS version: probably 3-4 years old. how can I see the version on the remote, shared server (no remote "control panel")
- i already have a workaround, so it's purely curiosity for now.

**EDIT: 2011-02-27**
I no longer have access to that code, and i lost interest in solving it anyway.

i thank the commenters so far.

Comment: The variables are in querystring or in the form collection?

Comment: That is so mad its hard to believe.  That being the case can you present a small but complete reproduction so that others can replicate the problem.

Comment: I would also be curious to see sample code for this behavior.

Comment: Server version would be helpful as well.

Comment: Make a copy of your code as it is for backup purposes. Take out the response.flush. Start removing code until either the behavior changes to be as expected or you are left with literally just the few lines that do the declaration of the variable, the assignment of the value to the variable from the request and whatever you are using to output the value. I would expect as you remove code you will find some piece of code that is doing something unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I have noticed in past that using generic "request" collection can cause problems. Please try and use request.querystring("z") or request.form("z") depending on your application usage. One thing that tripped me when using request("ID") was when I had a cookie named ID and also had querystring for ID.